# Laravel 5 relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, relationships

I have two tables. Like this

**

```
user_accounts               usersonglists
--------------              ---------------
id                          id
username                    user_account_id
slug                        etc..
etc..
```

**
I created a route like this

```
/u/{slug}/songlists
```

This relation method in songlist model

```
public function userAccounts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User\UserAccounts','user_account_id','id');
}
```

I created controller method like this

```
$songLists = $SongListRepository->getSongListsByUserSlug($slug);
```

This is getSongListByUserSlug($slug) method

```
$songList = $this->model->with('userAccounts')->get();
```

I want to get songlists by user with $slug.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method:

```php
$query = $this->model->with('userAccounts');

$query->whereHas('userAccounts', function($query) use ($slug) {
    $query->where('slug', $slug);
})

$lists = $query->get();
```

BTW, you should probably rename that `userAccounts` method to the singular `userAccount`.

---

An easier way might be to start from the account:

```php
$lists = UserAccount::where('slug', $slug)->songLists;
```

Assuming you've set up the inverse relationship.